# Images inserted via HTML into blog posts not rendered by Hugo

Tags: html, css, hugo

I'm using HTML snippets such as

```
<img src="site.jpg" style="width:100px; float:left; margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px" border="0" />
```

to insert scaled and offset images into blog posts in Hugo. Unfortunately I'm finding with the latest version of Hugo that images inserted this way are not rendering. If I do an image insert via Markdown, the images are inserted fine, but it appears impossible apply a style tag?

Any suggestions on how I can diagnose the issue here? I'm currently at a loss.

Comment: Why not just use Markdown if that works fine? might be best to add that to your question :)

Comment: @CodeMonkey AFAIK it's not possible to make these style specifications using Markdown. If I'm wrong about that, I'm all ears!

Comment: Ah, gotcha that the lack of style was the issue hadn't twigged when I read it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to keep the HTML out of the MD as much as possible; setting anything to "unsafe" always makes me a little nervous, and I presume that was the intention when the the parameter was named "unsafe"!

I think my first port of call would be to use the [figure shortcode](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/#figure), that supports a class name, as well as nice-to-haves like captions and titles (which may have accessiblity and SEO benefits).

```
{{< figure src="site.jpg" title="Cool Image" class="pull-left" >}}
```

If that doesn't suit, the options would be a custom shortcode, or target through pure css, you could use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to alternate images to the left and right if desired.

*Edit - Additional info*

Create a CSS file and link it in the head, for example I have  `<project-root>static/styles/main.css` and this in the head of my layout

```
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**Very important to note that `static` is not part of the url/href.**

Above I assigned the figure the class of `pull-left` so in main.css your style would look like

```
.pull-left{
    width:100px; 
    float:left; 
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
```

**Added details from [Link in Comments](https://www.banjocode.com/custom-css/)**

Best to make a copy of theme files rather than overwriting so create

```
layouts -> partials -> head.html
```

normally copied from

```
themes -> actual-theme -> layouts -> partials -> head.html
```

and add in the normal HTML link tag. (Fun bonus fact, themes are optional if you want to create from scratch)

You can also specify files in the config file

```
custom_css = ["css/custom.css"]
custom_js = ["js/custom.js"]
```

And use this code to add to the head.html

```
// css 
{{ range .Site.Params.custom_css -}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ . | absURL }}">
{{- end }}

// javascript
{{ range .Site.Params.custom_js -}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ . | absURL }}">
{{- end }}
```

Comment: I'd love to use figure shortcodes as well and set the unsafe flag back to false. ;-) Bear with me here for a moment, as I'm not versed in HTML/CSS. How would you go about defining those classes for aligning images left, right, and center? I _think_ I've seen something about specifying the CSS in the static/ folder. I made one attempt at defining a class for centering using CSS defined in that folder, but had no luck in getting Hugo to pick it up and yield the outcome I was looking for. Any tips you can provide would be super helpful! Thanks!

Comment: added some more info :)

Comment: just to be explicit, in what file would the <link> reference go? I'm not sure.

Comment: I found this example that covers what you are referring to: https://www.banjocode.com/custom-css/

Comment: Updated answer with details from the link, I know SO community normally dislikes following links in case of link rot

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that inline HTML was getting filtered out by Hugo. The following needed to be added to `config.toml` to allow the HTML to be inserted into the resulting pages.

```
[markup]
  [markup.goldmark]
    [markup.goldmark.renderer]
      unsafe = true
```

This came to pass in Hugo 0.60.0 with [CommonMark compliance](https://gohugo.io/news/0.60.0-relnotes/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I cleaned up your syntax a little.

```
<img src="site.jpg" style="width:100px; float:left; margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px; border:0px;" />
```